# Wiring a ceiling light fixture. Too many ceiling wires!

Tags: wiring

I have one bundle which includes 4 (old black wires) and one bundle which includes 3 (old black wires) and finally I have one wire by itself which appears fairly new. How do I identify my black/white and ground wire to hang my ceiling fixture?
Please Help!!!

Comment: How was the old fixture connected?

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't labelled, and isn't color coded, you will need to use a meter and do a lot of experimentation with the switches and circuit breakers to figure out what's going on. This is somewhere between annoying, messy, and dangerous if you don't know what you're doing.

If you need to ask this question I STRONGLY recommend that you bring in someone more experienced to deal with this. You are not looking at a homeowner-friendly situation.

Answer (score -1):

The old wires are all black, both the hot and the neutral. Probably one bundle is hot the other neutral. Don't know about the new wire.

Post a picture maybe?

What used to be there? How was it connected.

Use a Neon test lamp to figure out which is hot and which is neutral.